# How do I do custom gradient calculation for a PyTorch Tensor-like type?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am attempting to create a tensor-like class that I wish to integrate with PyTorch. The class will have to store the tensor values and gradients in a custom format. I've been following the instructions at [extending `torch` with a Tensor-like type](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html#extending-torch-with-a-tensor-like-type). I have questions especially pertaining to gradient storage and calculation:

1. I want to initialize my class from a (float) tensor and be able to convert it back. I know I can retrieve the values from the tensor using the numpy() function, but how do I get gradient data if I wish to store that too? Is directly accessing `tensor.grad` the correct way to do so? When I convert back to tensor, how can I give it back the stored gradient data?
2. In the above link I saw the instructions for making functions like `torch.add` work with my custom type, but that seems to only deal with the forward pass and I will also need to modify how the gradient is calculated by autograd. How do I define both the custom forward and backward versions of torch.add? Elsewhere, I saw the instructions for [extending `torch.autograd` with a custom function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html#extending-torch-autograd) but I am not sure if those instructions can be merged with this case. Is there a way I can create a custom add function and say that that function's `apply` implements `torch.add` for my class?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `tensor.grad.data` (check if `grad not None`!)
2. Can you perform the operation on the `torch.Tensor` directly or does it have to be your custom type? Then the tensor could carry the autograd information for most function (you would only compute the gradient yourself on custom functions). You could also consider subclassing `torch.Tensor`, that would alleviate a lot of those problems.

Comment: Similar to the tensor value, I want to store the tensor gradient in a custom format. So, I will need to be able to calculate gradients myself for all the functions I need. Will I be able to do this if I subclass `torch.Tensor` and use the custom storage format in the subclass?

Comment: The gradient is itself a `torch.Tensor` so you will probably have a derived `MainTensor(torch.Tensor)` and a `GradientTensor(torch.Tensor)` and you may have to implement your custom functions to deal with either.

Comment: I can't perform the operation directly on the tensor. Please elaborate, I'm not sure how to implement this answer. I've asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73532345/defining-my-own-gradient-function-for-pytorch-to-use