# Defining my own gradient function for pytorch to use

Tags: numpy, pytorch, tensor, torch

I want to feed pytorch gradients manually. In my real problem, I have my own adjoint function that does not use tensors. Is there any way I can define my own gradient function for pytorch to use during optimization?

```
import numpy as np
import torch

# define rosenbrock function and gradient
x0 = np.array([0.1, 0.1])
a = 1
b = 5
def f(x):
   return (a - x[0]) ** 2 + b * (x[1] - x[0] ** 2) ** 2

def jac(x):
   dx1 = -2 * a + 4 * b * x[0] ** 3 - 4 * b * x[0] * x[1] + 2 * x[0]
   dx2 = 2 * b * (x[1] - x[0] ** 2)
   return np.array([dx1, dx2])

# create stochastic rosenbrock function and gradient
# (the crude analogy is that I have predefined stochastic
#  forward and backward functions)
def f_rand(x):
   return f(x) * np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.5)

def jac_rand(x): return jac(x) * np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.5)


x_tensor = torch.tensor(x0, requires_grad=False)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([x_tensor], lr=0.1)

# here, closure is fed f_rand to compute the gradient.
# I need to feed closer the gradient directly from jac_rand
def closure():
   optimizer.zero_grad()
   loss = f_rand(x_tensor)
   loss.backward() # jac_rand(x)
   return loss

for ii in range(200):
   optimizer.step(closure) 

print(x_tensor, f(x_tensor))
  # tensor([1.0000, 1.0000], dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=True) tensor(4.5799e-09, dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
  # ( this is the right answer, E[f(1, 1)] = 0 )
```

I've tried defining a custom function, but I can't get it to work. This is my best attempt so far:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

# define rosenbrock function and gradient

x0 = np.array([0.1, 0.1])
a = 1
b = 5
def f(x):
   return (a - x[0]) ** 2 + b * (x[1] - x[0] ** 2) ** 2

def jac(x):
   dx1 = -2 * a + 4 * b * x[0] ** 3 - 4 * b * x[0] * x[1] + 2 * x[0]
   dx2 = 2 * b * (x[1] - x[0] ** 2)
   return np.array([dx1, dx2])

# create stochastic rosenbrock function and gradient
def f_rand(x):
   return f(x) * np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.5)

def jac_rand(x): return jac(x) * np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.5)

class custom_function(torch.autograd.Function):

    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input):
       ctx.save_for_backward(input)
       return f_rand(input)

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        input, = ctx.saved_tensors
        return grad_output * g_rand(input)

x_tensor = torch.tensor(x0, requires_grad=False)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([x_tensor], lr=0.1)

for ii in range(200):
   print('x_tensor ', x_tensor)
   optimizer.step(custom_function())

print(x_tensor, f(x_tensor))
```

It says:

`RuntimeError: Legacy autograd function with non-static forward method is deprecated. Please use new-style autograd function with static forward method. (Example: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.Function)`

Comment: Try here: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_autograd/polynomial_custom_function.html

Comment: @DerekG Thanks but the linked example doesn't quite work for me. I'd like to try using many different optimization algorithms, but this only uses a very basic SGD algorithm. I need something that works with `adam`. (in my real problem, I'd actually like to use this LBFGS approach: https://github.com/hjmshi/PyTorch-LBFGS)

Comment: I added my best attempt so far to use `torch.autograd.Function`

Comment: @kilojoules do you want something like: `x_tensor.grad = jac_rand(x_tensor)`?

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi I think so. When I do that, I get `assigned grad expected to be a Tensor or None but got grad of typenumpy.ndarray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure if this is exactly what you want but the method call `loss.backward()` computes gradients via pytorch's computational graph and stores the gradient values in the weight tensors themselves (in your case it's in `x_tensor`). And these gradients can be accessed via `x_tensor.grad`. However, if you don't want to use pytorch's gradient computing method using `loss.backward()`, then you can manually feed your gradients into your tensor's `.grad` attribute as follows:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    def closure():
       optimizer.zero_grad()
       loss = f_rand(x_tensor)
       x_tensor.grad = torch.from_numpy(jac_rand(x_tensor))
       return loss
```

Comment: Also note that since you already have the closed-form solution of your loss function's gradient, you don't need to actually compute the `loss`.

Answer (score 1):

I made some modifications, mainly the learning rate and the number of iterations. You will see the loss goes to zero as the tensor approaches (a, a²).

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import torch

# define rosenbrock function and gradient
np.random.seed(0)
x0 = np.array([0.1, 0.1])
a = 6
b = 100
def f(x):
    return (a - x[0]) ** 2 + b * (x[1] - x[0] ** 2) ** 2

def jac(x):
    dx1 = -2 * a + 4 * b * x[0] ** 3 - 4 * b * x[0] * x[1] + 2 * x[0]
    dx2 = 2 * b * (x[1] - x[0] ** 2)
    return np.array([dx1, dx2])

# create stochastic rosenbrock function and gradient
def f_rand(x):
    #return f(x)
    return f(x) * np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.5)

def jac_rand(x):
    #return jac(x)
    return jac(x) * np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.5)

class CustomFunction(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input):
        ctx.save_for_backward(input)
        return f_rand(input)

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        input, = ctx.saved_tensors
        return grad_output * jac_rand(input)
custom_function = CustomFunction.apply
x_tensor = torch.tensor(x0, requires_grad=True)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([x_tensor], lr=0.0001)
print('x_tensor ', x_tensor)
for ii in range(1000000):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output=custom_function(x_tensor)
    loss = round(output.item(),8)
    if loss < 0.0000001:
        print('loss: ',loss)
        break
    print('loss: ',loss)
    output.backward()
    optimizer.step()

print(x_tensor, f(x_tensor))
```